# Is there a CSS 'sibling contains' selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there any way I can use CSS to set the style of an element contingent on the class of a child if its sibling? Or of the child of a sibling of its parent?

For example, say I have this table:

```
<table>
    <tr><td><span class='red'>A</span></td><td><span class='blue'>B</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class='red'>C</span></td><td><span class='red'>D</span></td></tr>
</table>
```

And I want to select any SPAN which has a class "red", but only if an adjacent (in the same row) TD element contains a span with the class "blue". So, it would affect cell A, but not cell C. Is this possible? What's the closest I could get to selecting an element depending on the attributes of its siblings?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a CSS 'sibling contains' selector?

There is no 'contains' or parent selector in CSS, so in turn there is no 'sibling contains' or 'sibling is a parent of' selector.

> I want to select any SPAN which has a class "red", but only if an adjacent (in the same row) TD element contains a span with the class "blue". So, it would affect cell A, but not cell C. Is this possible? What's the closest I could get to selecting an element depending on the attributes of its siblings?

Sibling combinators only allow you to match an element based on its siblings at the same level, using what's already available to you (e.g. IDs, classes, pseudo-classes and attributes).

In your case, your `span` elements aren't siblings of each other at all, but their parent `td`s are. But since there's no parent selector as mentioned, you can't select the child of the first `td` based on the child of its sibling. So, with your current markup, it's not possible to do with using just CSS.

Answer (score 0):

There is the adjacent (`+`) and general ( `~`) sibling selectors, but that still won't hep you with your current markup, as explained by @BoltClock. However if you changed your markup to:

```
<table>
    <tr><td class="red><span>A</span></td><td class="blue"><span>B</span></td></tr>
</table>
```

ie. move your classes to the `<td>`s instead of the `<span>`s you should have more luck:

`td.red + td.blue` would select all `td.blue` elements that *follow* a `td.red` element.